# Unable to clone git repo from script with the same ssh key

Tags: bash, git, ssh-keys

If I manually enter the following commands in a terminal:

```
cd ~
pwd
ssh-add -l
cd ~/Documents
git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git
```

I get the following output

```
/Users/ray
4096 SHA256:gwPuz8TpL0IRIp3k/DSsPqNEFrqZrXaeymSLspOIg41 /Users/ray/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
2048 SHA256:x0eBEFCwhfQ3K6VnM7C6w6dTV+l9TWFzRe5eJI3cYX1 /Users/ray/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 7316, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2232/2232), done.
remote: Total 7316 (delta 3420), reused 7242 (delta 3397)
Receiving objects: 100% (7316/7316), 826.72 KiB | 1.78 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3420/3420), done.
```

If I then put those same lines in a script and run it I get the same output but if a different user (root) runs it I get this output:

```
/Users/ray
4096 SHA256:gwPuz8TpL0IRIp3k/DSsPqNEFrqZrXaeymSLspOIg41 /Users/ray/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
2048 SHA256:x0eBEFCwhfQ3K6VnM7C6w6dTV+l9TWFzRe5eJI3cYX1 /Users/ray/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
Cloning into 'repo'...
Unauthorized
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What ssh key is Git using? Or is there another reason this is being rejected?

EDIT: 
I have also tried changing the permissions and ownership on the id_rsa files

EDIT:
I was able to bypass the issue by calling `sudo -H -u ray git clone...`

Comment: "What ssh key is Git using?" - The default one, `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`. `root` would not be looking at your correct key

Comment: `ray` and `root` are two different users. You need to add the public ssh key of `root` to bitbucket.

Comment: But they both report `/Users/ray` as their home dirs and running `ssh-add -l` gives the same keys back

Comment: Did you add your SSH key to `ssh-agent` for root user?

Comment: @Eray I did try adding ssh-add `/Users/ray/.ssh/id_rsa` to both and got the same results

Comment: @Amadan But `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` is the same file for both users (it's `/Users/ray/.ssh/id_rsa` for whatever reason)